# How can I pass a boxed member of a borrowed struct to a function without copying it?

Tags: rust, move, box

In my example I get an error:

> cannot move out of borrowed content

```
struct BigData {}

struct Data {
    x: Box<BigData>,
}

fn calc_data(x: Box<BigData>) {}

fn main() {
    let b = BigData {};
    let d = Data { x: Box::new(b) };
    let borrowed_d = &d;
    calc_data(borrowed_d.x); //error: cannot move out of borrowed content
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=struct%20BigData%7B%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Data%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20Box%3CBigData%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20calc_data(x%3A%20Box%3CBigData%3E)%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20BigData%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20d%20%3D%20Data%7Bx%3A%20Box%3A%3Anew(b)%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20borrowed_d%20%3D%20%26d%3B%0A%20%20%20%20calc_data(borrowed_d.x)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just borrow the boxed member and pass by reference:

```
struct BigData {}

struct Data {
    x: Box<BigData>,
}

fn calc_data(x: &Box<BigData>) {}

fn main() {
    let b = BigData {};
    let d = Data { x: Box::new(b) };
    let borrowed_d = &d;
    calc_data(&borrowed_d.x);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b32fb63faa73df0efd25f927aec069db&version=stable&backtrace=0)

But it's unlikely you actually want to pass a reference to the box rather than the `BigData` itself, so you can just do:

```
fn calc_data(x: &BigData) {}
```

and call it in the same way (`&Box<T>` automatically converts to `&T`).

Comment: Although you probably wouldn't really want to pass `&Box<BigData>` unless you specifically want to work with the `Box` (and there's not a lot you can do with it immutably). Probably `calc_data` should just take `&BigData` and let the caller worry about whether it's boxed or not

Comment: Is it a idiomatic way? I mean &Box ? What about performance? Looks like another level of indirection here or it will be optimized by compiler?

Comment: Thanks, I agree that's better.

Comment: In real code I have Boxed trait, not boxed structure. So i don't know is it possible to use it without box as a struct member. Can i use something like &MyTrait instead of Box<MyTrait> ?

Comment: ... but you need to call it as `calc_data(&*borrowed_d.x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `calc_data` consumes its argument; you can't consume `x` when `d` is borrowed, though. If you don't want to change the signature of `calc_data` you need to drop the borrow.

```
fn main() {
    let b = BigData {};
    let d = Data { x: Box::new(b) };
    calc_data(d.x);
}
```

Since you are consuming the argument, the boxed data is not copied.

Comment: In this simple  example borrowing is not needed, but in real code this needed

Comment: @AlexanderAntoshuk in that case you probably need to restructure your code, e.g. put the borrow in its own scope.